# AutoMapper sets EF Core entities to detach state

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, automapper

When I map my input model with my database entities using AutoMapper, entity states are changes to 'detached' which means, that the changes aren't saved to the database.

```
CreateMap<User, UserInput>().ReverseMap();
```

Add/Update:

```
[BindProperty]
public IList<UserInput> UsersInput { get; set; }

public async Task<PageResult> OnGetAsync()
{

    var users = await _dbContext.Users.ToListAsync();
    UsersInput = _mapper.Map<List<UsersInput>>(signers);

    return Page();

}

public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{

    var users = await _dbContext.Users.ToListAsync();

    foreach (var u in users)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_dbContext.Entry(u).State); // => Unchanged
    }

    users = _mapper.Map(UsersInput, users);

    foreach (var u in users)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_dbContext.Entry(u).State); // => Detached
    }

    // Save and return

    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(); // => Nothing is saved because entities are Detached

    return Page();

}
```

Has it something to do with the way I map the data?

Comment: Theoretically it should work without the assignement. Have you tried `_mapper.Map(UsersInput, users);` ?

Comment: You're right, but that doesn't change anything.

Comment: I have never tried using the (src,dest) mapper call with a collection... I highly doubt that would work reliably to know to map which source element with which destination element. I'd suggest iterating through the modified list, fetch the entity from users and use `_mapper.Map(modified, entity)` within the loop and see if that alters the behaviour.

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection.EFCore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as `UsersInput` has an id that corresponds to the id in the Users table, then there's no reason to load anything from the DB. Just use the EF Core `UpdateRange()` method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    var users = _mapper.Map<List<User>>(UsersInput);
    _dbContext.Users.UpdateRange(users);
    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    return Page();
}
```

Comment: The UserInput has an id, so I delete the db query from the OnPost and do like in your example. But still, when I foreach the users, they're detached.

Comment: Well, actually it works. When I write the state, it's detached, but the changes are saved to the database. Thanks!

Comment: `UpdateRange` has disadvantage - it updates ALL fields. If you have a lot of indexes and table is huge, think twice before using it.