# DotNet EF 7 ignores changes in List<string> after mapping using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, automapper, sql-server-express

I am trying to fetch an object from an SQL-Express DB, map a new object to the it using AutoMapper, and then save changes to the DB with the updated properties.

The source class properties:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
public List<string> Roles { get; set; } = new List<string>();
```

The destination class:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
public User? User { get; set; }
public List<string> Roles { get; set; } = new List<string>();
public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; } = new List<Employee>();
```

The code:

```
var business = await context.Businesses
    .Include(b => b.User)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(b => b.Id == newBusiness.Id);

if (...) // NULL CHECK
{
    ....
}

mapper.Map(newBusiness, business);

await context.SaveChangesAsync();

response.Data = mapper.Map<GetBusinessDto>(business);
```

The problem is that the property "Roles" of type List is not being changed on the DB, even though it is being mapped properly to the local variable "business".
The other property "Name" is being updated properly on the DB.

Here are the request and the results:

```
// The request I sent to the server:
{
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Testing",
  "roles": [
    "NewRole"
  ]
}

// The response I got:
{
  "data": {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Testing",
    "roles": [
      "NewRole"
    ],
...
}

// Now when I get this object from the server:
{
  "data": {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Testing",
    "roles": [
      "Bartender"
    ],
...
}
```

I tried debugging and noticed that the local object "business" is changed but for some reason only the "Name" property is updated on the server. The weird thing is that the issue is fixed when I add this line to the mapper configuration:

```
CreateMap<UpdateBusinessDto, Business>()
                .AfterMap((src, dest) => dest.Roles = src.Roles); // THIS LINE
```

Why would it work? The problem wasn't with the mapper in the first place but somehow AfterMap() fixed it.
I don't want to depend on adding this line all the time. I don't even know what caused it.

I'm confused.

EDIT:

Thanks to CodeCaster I understood what the problem is.
I found this: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection.EFCore
But that didn't fix it.

I also found this: [AutoMapper sets EF Core entities to detach state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74373343/automapper-sets-ef-core-entities-to-detach-state)

and at first it told me I can't track an object that is already being tracked. So I commented these parts and it worked:

```cs
//var business = await context.Businesses
//    .Include(b => b.User)
//    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(b => b.Id == newBusiness.Id);

//if (...) // NULL CHECK 
//{
//    ...
//}


//mapper.Map(newBusiness, business);

var updated = mapper.Map<Business>(newBusiness);
context.Businesses.Update(updated);

await context.SaveChangesAsync();

response.Data = mapper.Map<GetBusinessDto>(updated);
```

Is this the right way to do this? How can I still check the item before I update it?

Comment: Mapping disconnects objects.

Comment: Care to elaborate?

Comment: If you use AutoMapper on your entites, Entity Framework's change tracker loses the connection to the objects it knows it loaded from the database.

Comment: Then why did it work for "Name"? and why did the AfterMap function fixed it?

Comment: Because first-level value-type properties (such as `string Name`) are assigned by value. Complex types (lists, objects) are assigned by reference, and as soon as AutoMapper reassigns it (it creates a _new_ list), EF doesn't see its known list anymore. By reassigning the source Roles list, you're reassigning the list known to EF.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot,  I think I got it. But I still couldn't fix it entirely. Please read my edited post to see if you can help.